# Moving windows against desktop background leaves a persistent trail which can only be cleared by going into activity overview

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-gnome

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and Nvidia driver version 346.82.

When I move a window and the desktop is visible on my centre monitor, there is a trailing window drawn. The trail is only cleared after viewing the activity overview (when super key is pressed on the keyboard).

This only happens on the centre display. The centre display is the only display to have a black bar at the top when viewed in display settings (I assume this means that it is the primary display).

screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: I am having this exact problem, was a solution ever found?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue which seems like it was being caused by trying to set my monitor positioning using xrandr. Once I removed my startup script and renamed the .config file in my home directory so that a new one was created after logging back in, everything seems to be working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It started after upgrading from ubuntu 16 (xenial) to 18 (bionic). The window manager is openbox. It worked fine in 16, but in 18 it started leaving trails on the root window. Solution: placed 'xcompmgr -n &' at the start of ~/.config/openbox/autostart.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on VirtualBox 7.0. on Windows. I just turned off 'Enable 3D acceleration' in VirtualBox's Display settings for the virtual machine, solving the problem completely.